# Multiple Criteria Search from List Menus

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to make a search where a user can be able to search for certain establishments (night-clubs) based on certain criteria.

When entering an establishment, certain details are selected from drop down list menus e.g.

### Location:  (only one can be selected)

```
Westlands
Eastleigh
Langata
Kamukunji
Dagoretti
Starehe 
Makadara
```

### Pricing:  (only one can be selected)

```
Very Cheap
Inexpensive
Moderate
Expensive 
Very Expensive
```

### Main Music Genre Played (only one can be selected)

```
Various
Rock
Hip Hop/R & B
Soul
Country
Pop
House
```

### Club Interests (I have check boxes for this as there could be more than one selected)

```
Shoot Pool
Karaoke
Lounge
Live Band
Dance
Watch Sports
```

How would I implement a search for instance to:

```
1. Allow a users to list all clubs that are located in Westlands?
2. Allow a user to list all clubs where he can play pool and watch a basketball game?
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you add a criteria in each dropdown lists that means "all values are used for the search".

```
-- ALL --
Very Cheap
Inexpensive
Moderate
Expensive 
Very Expensive
```

Comment: I dont quite understand. I would like to have an identical list menu for say prices whereby when i select very cheap, all establishments that have very cheap in their prices column show up

Comment: I was thinking about the conceptual implementation of the search. You should present to the user some dropdown lists with your criteria. Each list present your criteria plus one for "all". 

If you was talking about the programmatic phase you should ask a question for each problem you have. We're not there to implement your solution but to help you;)

Comment: Thanks for your replys. I posted a more detailed problem based on my issue here. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5144428/criteria-search-based-on-textfield-and-a-list-menu)